# Is regret worth?

Tags: karma, sutras, buddha

Today I regret for a sparrow was wandering around running ceiling fan.
Even I had noticed and think to turn it off but I forget.

I don't care if it was my bad karma which is not important than saving a sparrow    but does really a matter for saving it then it wasn't a bad karma.

I'm not afraid if I've break precept or my bad krama, what else I need to pay for it.

I can't revert a time neither get a sparrow alive.
I don't have anything left than **regret**.
Does it worth?

Anything defined in sutta about regret or what Lord Buddha said about ***regret***?

Comment: See the Buddhas [teachings to his Son Rahula](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.061.than_en.html). Once seeing that something caused harm (by speech, body), talk to a admirable friend, resolve no more doing it. In case of thought, just ashamed, and resolve no more doing it. Fans are killer, 100 hour for hour, for some sense pleasures, and also not healthy. No need to make use of such at all. Used to without such, healthier bodily and mental.

Comment: @Samana Johann Thank you Bhante. I should be altert and must be acitve for such situations so I could help to lives around me.  Thank you so much

Comment: One with perfect Sila, seeing the backwards of sensuality, has no more need in rescue and many kinds of Dana, isn't anymore that busy to run arround that nothing breaks. Mudita, Nyom Swapnil.

Comment: To the question "is regret worthy", yes, one of the three [governing principles](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.040.than_en.html), leading all the way to liberation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about what you could have done and should have not done is part of [Nīvaraṇa](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/32.1-Nivarana.-piya.pdf) more particularly [Uddhacca,kukkucca](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/32.7-Uddhaccakukkucca-piya.pdf). Since you cannot turn back time or remedy the situation it is best you do not worry about this. Worrying will aggravate the situation.

If you knew the sparrow was in danger but chose it to ignore it this is negligence. This does not amount to killing but this may have karmic consequences.

If you did not occur that the sparrow was in danger and if hit the fan and died there is no karmic consequences.

Comment: So I thing ***Nivarana*** means ***Prevention*** . In my case I didn't ignored, it just happened because I was busy and as if fan blades hit it's body I realized that it's gone. and I regret. As I said I'm not afraid if it is my bad karma or will may have karmic consequences but it does really matter for good deeds. My aim was just save a life.

Answer (score 0):

"What is the purpose of skillful virtues? What is their reward?"

"Skillful virtues have freedom from remorse as their purpose, Ananda, and freedom from remorse as their reward."

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an11/an11.001.than.html